# How can I prove that $\frac{x}{\ln(x)} < \pi(x)$ for $x \geq 17$?

Tags: prime-numbers

I saw on Wikipedia that $\frac{x}{\ln(x)} < \pi(x)$ for $x \geq 17$ but it doesn't provide the proof. What is the proof for this and are there any legitimate papers that I can cite?

Comment: Wikipedia does not provide a proof but gives a reference. That paper by J. Barkley Rosser and Lowell Schoenfeld contains this inequality (Corollary 1) with a reference to D. N. Lehmer's list of primes.